# How to hide files with a specific extension

Tags: nautilus, hidden-files

I have set of temp files created in my folder with `.bak` extensions. How can I make them hide by default in Ubuntu?

I tried adding a .hidden file with *.bak as entry in the file, but that is not working. Any help is very appreciated...

Comment: IMO you're trying to fix the problem at the wrong end. If a program creates lots of backup files, it should put them in a dedicated folder and not spam them somewhere else.

Comment: i have a shared dropbox folder where the backup files are getting created by another shared user. So i cant change it at that end. Need to fix at my end...

Comment: I found this post (ubuntu forums). I hope this can help you. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=789684

Comment: I think the question also applies to auxiliary files generated by compilers. The feature to hide files in Nautilus would be great to have. @htorque, It is not realistic to ask users to reprogram software that generate useless files. Even if the files have some use, it can still be desirable the possibility to hide them.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little script I wrote for hiding LaTeX intermediate files:

```
alias hidetex='ls *?(aux|bbl|blg|brf|lof|log|lot|out|toc) -1 > .hidden'
```

I added it to the **~/.bash_aliases** file, so now I just `cd` to the folder I want to hide the files, and type `hidetex`.

This is intended to be executed at specific folders, but you could make it more generic (e.g. for .bak files) and change it to perform the task recursively, adding a .hidden file to each folder, but that's a little more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a file called `.hidden` in your home directory. In this file you can put the names of all the files that you would like to be hidden, one per line.

Answer (score 0):

If you place a full stop (or period) at the beginning of the name of the file it should hide it, for example:

.helloworld.txt

To view your now hidden file, click "view" on Nautilus then check "Show Hidden Files".

Comment: Thank you for the tip. But they are created by a program, i cant rename each of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you and the program don't care about the name of the file, try this command:

```
for annoyingbak in *.bak; do mv "$annoyingbak" ."$annoyingbak"; done
```

Then run it whenever you're annoyed by the .baks. It moves every file named `bla.bak` to `.bla.bak`.

If you have to do it very often, add this to the end of your `.bashrc`:

```
function deannoy {
    for annoyingbak in *.bak; do 
        mv "$annoyingbak" ."$annoyingbak"
    done
}
```

Then you can just type `deannoy` in your Dropbox folder and they're gone.

Comment: I suggest you read [Bash Pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) points 1 and 2.

Comment: oh hehe... I just use bash for the things I need in everyday tasks I (obv.) never really learned it. Good advice thanks! mv *.bak *.bak~ is the better way anyway