# Script to un-hide files with specific extention in folders reccursively

Tags: bash, scripts

I have this folder that contains many folders, each containing many files with the name structure .XYZ.zip.

I'd like to rename them (using bash) to XYZ.zip (i.e. un-hide them).

I've seen [a question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11746/how-to-hide-files-with-a-specific-extension) attempting to do a similar thing,

```
alias deannoy='for annoyingbak in *.bak;do mv "$annoyingbak" ."$annoyingbak";done'>> ~/.bashrc && . .bashrc
```

but I've not been able to manage to change so it's done recursively for all folders 
down from the current folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for ... in *.bak` command searches only the current directory.

You want instead to use the `find` command, which searches recursively. This command will locate all zip files starting with a dot at any depth in the current directory (`.`).

```
find . -iname '.*.zip'
```

Removing the leading dot is a bit trickier though. The following seems to work (but may have edge cases, caveat emptor).

```
for f in $(find -iname '.*.zip'); do f2=$(echo $f | sed -re 's/(.*)\/\.(.*)/\1\/\2/'); echo $f $f2; done
```

This will print all the operations it would perform (`echo $f $f2`), if this list looks right change it to `mv $f $f2` and it will do the renames.

Comment: this is my personal favorite (but i can't try it now, the computer on which the files reside is busy....): simplest [also good that it we can do a dry run]

Answer (score 3):

There is a good answer on sister-site [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154166/how-to-recursively-list-subdirectories-in-bash-without-using-find-or-ls-commands): It says:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> recurse() {
>  for i in "$1"/*;do
>     if [ -d "$i" ];then
>         echo "dir: $i"
>         recurse "$i"
>     elif [ -f "$i" ]; then
>         echo "file: $i"
>     fi
>  done
> }
>
> recurse /path
> ```
>
> OR if you have bash 4.0
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> shopt -s globstar
> for file in /path/**
> do
>     echo $file
> done
> ```

Say thank you over at stackexchange to ghostdog74 if this works for you. The askubuntu account will work there too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command:

```
$ find foobar/ -type f -iname ".*" -exec rename -n 's/^(.+)\/\.(.+)$/$1\/$2/' '{}' \;

foobar/sub_dir/moresubdir/.foo bar.zip renamed as foobar/sub_dir/moresubdir/foo bar.zip
foobar/sub_dir/moresubdir/.one.zip renamed as foobar/sub_dir/moresubdir/one.zip
foobar/sub_dir/moresubdir/.two.zip renamed as foobar/sub_dir/moresubdir/two.zip
foobar/sub_dir/.one.zip renamed as foobar/sub_dir/one.zip
foobar/sub_dir/.two.zip renamed as foobar/sub_dir/two.zip
foobar/.foo bar.zip renamed as foobar/foo bar.zip
foobar/.one.zip renamed as foobar/one.zip
foobar/.two.zip renamed as foobar/two.zip
```

`find` will recursively search for all hidden files then pass them to `rename`. The `-n` param causes rename to dry-run the substitution rule to show you what those files would be renamed to. If you're happy with the results, remove the param so it renames the files for real