# How to hide files in Nautilus according to their extension?

Tags: nautilus, extension

I want to hide all `*.o` files from Nautilus in a specific folder. Is there a way to do it? If yes, how?

Comment: I think you can not generally hide all `*.o` files in a directory, but you can make a list of complete file names that should be hidden, as described in [How to hide files with a specific extension](https://askubuntu.com/q/11746/367990) or [How to hide files and folders in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/q/143315/367990)